# How to toggle inspect tools using js?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a button which will toggle chrome developer/inspect tools. This may sound silly but I just want to know if it is possible to do.

```js
btn = document.querySelector('#test')
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  jQuery.event.trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : 123 });
  
  console.log('open inspect window')
})

$('body').keypress(function(e) {
  alert(e.which);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='test'>Toggle Dev Tools</button>
```

I tried triggering f12 key which is an shortcut to dev tools, but it didn't work (i dunno why).

What I think is keypress won't work on function keys, therefore we need keydown which is working for some reason. I changed 'type' to 'keydown' instead of 'keypress'

If anyone could help or explain that would be really helpful

Comment: As far as I can see, this is not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am trying to make a button which will toggle chrome developer/inspect tools. This may sound silly but I just want to know if it is possible to do.

No API is provided that would make this possible.

> I tried triggering f12 key which is an shortcut to dev tools, but it didn't work (i dunno why).

Events don't bubble outside the document and into the browser UI.